# Write 2 arrays to a .csv file and begin a new line after the end of the first array

Tags: objective-c, csv

i want to create a .csv file. The first row contains the header, the second row contains the values.

This is what I've done so far:

```
NSArray *theCSVFileHeaders = @[ @"GENDER", @"TITLE", @"FIRSTNAME", @"LASTNAME"];
NSArray *theCSVFileValues = @[ @"1", @"1", @"John", @"Doe" ];
NSArray *tmp = [theCSVFileHeaders arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:theCSVFileValues];
NSString *theCSVString = [tmp componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"The CSV String: %@", theCSVString);
```

And the output looks something like this

```
The CSV String: GENDER,TITLE,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,1,1,John,Doe
```

So, how can I start a newline after the last Header value to have an output like this?

```
GENDER,TITLE,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
1,1,John,Doe
```

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Your logic is not correct =>`NSArray *tmp = @[theCSVFileHeaders, theCSVFileValues]; NSMutableString *theCSVString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSArray *aLineArray in tmp) {[theCSVString appendString:[aLinArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]]; [theCSVString:@"\n"];}`

Comment: Thank you @Larme this helps a lot!

Comment: Please note that your code will produce bad CSV files if any of the values contains a comma, a double quote, or a newline.